# How to get ruby class name when an exception is thrown in Ruby

Tags: ruby, exception, ruby-on-rails-2, unhandled-exception, rescue

Cracking down an age-old ruby application written in version 1.8.7
to log all the unhandled exceptions overriding **rescue_action_in_public** by **rescue_action_in_public_with_custom**. I can see the error stack. However, if I can extract the error originator class name, it would be a great help. For example -

```
module Module1
   module Module2
      class Trap
         raise 'exception raised and not handled'
         def do_something
            raise 'something happened in runtime and not handled'
         end
      end
   end
end
```

I want to log the class name "Trap" from within **rescue_action_in_public_with_custom**. Any help/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but what is `rescue_action_in_public`?

Comment: @Stefan aparently it is a rails 2 method [`ActionController::Rescue#rescue_action_in_public`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Rescue/rescue_action_in_public)

Comment: The code above raises during class loading stage btw.

Comment: You could log the exception's [`backtrace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Exception.html#method-i-backtrace) and traverse the listed file locations to find the root cause.

Comment: Yes @Stefan you are right about logging the backtrace, which is done already using airbrake/errbit. As its a huge traffic application, now we want these logs in [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack) stack to find out the pattern and prioritize.

Answer (score 1):

Something to think about is using a customized error type -

```
class ErrorsWithCallerClass < StandardError # or something more appropriate
    attr_reader :klass
    def initialize(msg, klass) 
       @klass = klass 
       super(msg)
    end
end
```

then use that with

```
raise ErrorsWithCallerClass.new("bad stuff", Trap)
```